# Symlinking /var/lib to another partition

Tags: partition, symlink

Sorry if this question is too similar to others, I didn't find anything that helped me.

Following "best practices" I installed my debian with partitions: root, tmp, var and home. Also for the sizes I followed recommendations I read, but after using it for some time it seems for tmp and var I gave too little which gives me problems every now and then.

In order to give more space to var, I decided to symlink /var/cache -> /home/myuser/varcache and then /var/lib -> /home/myuser/varlib. the first seemed to work well, but the second seems to be a bad idea. Actually I see that instead of having /var/lib I have /var/lib/sudo and /var/lib/varlib, which is the actual symlink. Of course some things are not working, so I'm trying to revert it.

Does it make sense that it creates this weird /var/lib/varlib instead of just /var/lib?

Any recommendation on what to do instead?

Would it be a good idea to symlink some folder inside /var/lib instead?

Comment: Why put those directories under `/home/myuser`?  They don't belong in a user's home directory, ever.  create `/home/var`, `/home/var/lib`, `/home/var/cache` instead.  BTW `mv`+`symlink` is a method with a long history, people have done what you are doing for decades. because it works.

Comment: Good point. It was a very bad idea. Afterwards I did it for specific folders inside var and it went better in terms of just gaining space. After this experience I will create a root partition an another for home, but not partitions for var and tmp because it gave me problems running out of space.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it created /var/lib/varlib because you reversed the order of arguments in the `ln -s` command.

Like almost all unix commands, the order is source followed by destination. `ln -s /home/myuser/varlib /var/lib` will create a symlink called varlib in /var/lib. `ln -s /var/lib /home/myser/varlib` will create a symlink called varlib in /home/myuser

Try (as root, in single-user mode so nothing has any files open under /var/lib):

```
rm -f /var/lib/varlib
mkdir -p /home/var
mv /var/lib /home/var/
ln -s /home/var/lib /var/lib
```

If you want, you can also move the other symlinked dir out of your home directory (where they *really* do not belong) and into /home/var:

```
mv /home/myuser/varcache /home/var/cache
rm -f /var/cache
ln -s /home/var/cache /var/cache
```

Comment: It's a good point. But it was not because of the wrong order. Actually I did it for several folder the same way and it's only for that one that I got this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use LVM, you can increase `/var`. If not, what will be the biggest folder in `/var/lib`? Maybe mysql? If so, you should move mysql dir to your `/home/myuser/mysql` and make symlink.